# how to launch x programs running in mac ox from cygwin running on windows-

Tags: macos, cygwin, remote-access

running cygwin on windows I can connect and execute X applications with no further problems
just accessing the remote linux box as ssh -Y -l user machine.
If I do the same against a mac box and try to open ie. firefox as: open -a firefox
returns the following:
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/Firefox.app with error -10810.

Any hints?

I've alternatively used a vnc server in the mac computer, but it's extremely slow.
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/Applications/Firefox.app is not an X app it uses Apple's own GUI routines to write to the screen.

To work via cygwin you would need to compile up an X11 version of Firefox - one easy way is look at macports for X11 applications.

However I suspect you want to use Apple applications - all those in /Applications and then VNC is about the only way,

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mark.

The only other solution that might work is using AppleScript to script the target applications.   As far as I know, it doesn't require a GUI session.  I know I've used it over SSH before, but I can't remember if I've been logged in or not.  Worst case scenario, you just log in via VNC and then close your VNC client.

What are you trying to run?  Hopefully not just Firefox -- it'd be much easier to just use it on Linux than try to use it over VNC to a Mac.  Either can be frustratingly slow over a distance, in my experience, however.

Comment: Thanks both Mark and Benjamin. I'm trying to test a plugin in different platforms, this is why Firefox. I thought as a newbie mac user that the apps where all X11...
Thanks for answers,
Julian

Comment: You might try something like Selenium, if possible.  I've never tried doing much with plugins, but you might find more resources at openqa.org.